# Solving equation in Clifford algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

Let $g_i$ denote the $i$'th orthonormal basis of a Clifford algebra $G_{p,q}$, then any number in Clifford domain can be represented as follows: 
$$a=\sum_{i=1}^{2^{p+q}}(a_ig_{i})$$ where $a_i$ is some real coefficient.

Given Clifford numbers $a,b\in G_{p,q}$ how can I in general solve the following equation for the Clifford number $x=\sum_{i=1}^{2^{p+q}}(x_ig_{i})$, $x \in G_{p,q}$,?

$$(\sum_{i=1}^{2^{p+q}}(x_i(g_{i})^3))(-b)x = (\sum_{i=1}^{2^{p+q}}(a_i(g_{i})^3))ba$$

Comment: What's relation between $x$ and $x_i$?

Comment: Source? Context?

Comment: @ShuchangZhang $$x=\sum_{i=1}^{2^{p+q}}(x_ig_{i})$$

Comment: @ShuchangZhang  Consider the case of $G_{0,1}$, then this clifford algebra is isomorphic to complex numbers, so $g_1=1$ and $g_2=i$. Then $g_1^3=1$ and $g_2^3=i*i*i=-i$.

Comment: @rschwieb The actual equation uses the operator from my previous question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269335/an-operator-in-clifford-algebra  With this operator it looks like $x^*(-b)x=a^*ba$.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang $G_{p,q}$ is a Clifford algebra over $R^{p+q}$ where $p$ orthonormal basis vectors of $R^{p+q}$ square to $1$ and $q$ orthonormal basis vectors of $R^{p+q}$ square to $-1$. For example $G_{1,1}$ is defined over $R^2$ which has the orthonormal basis of $e_1 = [1,0]^T$ and $e_2=[0,1]^T$ for which we define that $e_1^2=1$ and $e_2^2=-1$. Then the basis of our clifford algebra is given by $g_1=1$, $g_2=e_1$, $g_3=e_2$, and $g_4=e_1 e_2$. Then we have that $g_1^2=1^2=1$, $g_2^2=e_1^2=1$, $g_3^2=e_2^2=-1$, and $g_4^2=(e_1 e_2)^2=e_1 e_2 e_1 e_2 = -e_1 e_1 e_2 e_2 = -e_1^2 e_2^2 = 1$.

Comment: In the previous question, it was said this "cubing" is really just clifford conjugation?  That is, a composition of reversal and grade involution?